# Project calling method in one solution

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Now added 3 projects in one solution.

When I called 2nd projects form calling using this code

```
Dim frm as New Project2.Form1
frm.show()
Me.Hide()
```

Now, I want to hidden window to be unhide when I click the exit button in `project2.Form1`

```
Project1.Home.Show()
Me.Close()
```

but in Project2 not showing Project1 at the time of making code

Comment: What is your question? Please [edit] and provide a [repro].

Comment: Why are you hiding the first form to begin with? It's VERY rare that that is a good thing. Why not just call `ShowDialog` instead, so the second form is displayed as a modal dialogue? The first form will then be inaccessible until the second form closes but there's no need to reshow it.

Comment: If you really must hide the first form then it's not up to the second form to reshow it. The second form just closes itself because it doesn't even know the first form exists. The first form would handle the `FormClosed` event of the second and then reshow itself.